# Ao clicar em um link alterar dentro da tag vídeo o valor de ser para o link clicado

Tags: javascript, vídeo

Tenho uma lista de filmes em mp4 na página em uma lista li são 1000 links que abrem direto no navegador.

A questão é que criei um iframe que recebem os links vai target mais alguns links ele inicia um download do mp4.

Então eu queria usar ao invés do iframe a tag vídeo do html5 que dá certo e exibe o filme sem fazer o download.

Só que não quero criar 1000 tags vídeo e sim uma só que apenas troca o atributo src de acordo com o link clicado.

Answer (score -1):

Em resumo você teria que fazer conforme demonstrado no código abaixo.

1º Definir os links todos com o mesmo `class`;

2º Colocar um `id` único para cada link, conforme mostrado no exemplo abaixo;

3º Inserir o `case` para cada link, definindo o endereço `src` de cada vídeo.

```js
$('.linkvideo').click(function(){
   var link = $(this).attr('id');
   switch(link){ 
      case 'link1':
 $('#fonteVideo').attr('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4');
 $("#divVideo video")[0].load();
        break;
      case 'link2':
         $('#fonteVideo').attr('src', 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4');
  $("#divVideo video")[0].load();
         break;
    }
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="link1" class="linkvideo">Link1</a><br><br>
  
<a href="#" id="link2" class="linkvideo">Link2</a><br><br>
  
<div id="divVideo">
   <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source id="fonteVideo" src="">
   </video>
</div>
```